# Struct/Enum vs Class for network calls

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, swift5

I always wondered which is the right way or efficient way to handle common network code. I have a common place for each feature's network calls. the objective is to fetch data, decode and return it back to the caller  e.g below

questions

1. should we use struct/enum/class for this? and why?
2. by using struct for such similar functionality, do we increase the app size?

```
protocol ModuleNetworkProvider {
func getDetails(for identifier, completion: @escaping (detailsObject?, Error?) -> ()) 
}

struct ModuleNetwork: ModuleNetworkProvider {
    func getDetails(for identifier, completion: @escaping (detailsObject?, Error?) -> ()) {
        NetworkManager.sessionManager.request(getDetails) { response
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let detailsObjectData = try JSONDecoder().decode(detailsObject.self, from: data)
                    completion(detailsObjectData, nil)
                } catch(let error) {
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Services are generally reference types. You neither need nor particularly want value semantics.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a "correct" way.
The guidelines that I would follow.

- Don't use static functions, makes it harder to test. You can use Dependency Injection, but I personally prefer to resolve the service that does the API calls.
- Use a protocol, makes it is easier to test, you can even generate a mock automatically with [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery).
- If you only need to call something and pass the result, struct can do it as well.
- If you need to pass the instance around often, class probably is better than struct.
- If in your logic, you also need to put some data in database, you do both data fetching and storing data, most likely you need to go with a class. Even struct will work if you don't mutate self, you can add the database service in the capture list.
- **Be consistent.**

I know that some of you might not agree with all above.

Another option is declaring dependencies as closures, and creating environments for each scope (ex: a View, a feature, etc), the topic is a bit more complicated, check [Pointfree](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture/discussions/522), they even have a real app, [isowords](https://github.com/pointfreeco/isowords), to see better in practice this principle.

Comment: thanks this helps a lot. But do struct create a new copy when passed around in different model ( not edited)

Comment: If you pass it and store it, than yes, it is copied, if you pass it and just use it, then it is not copied. If you add it to the capture list, it is copied. Structs are value type, check apple documentation for more details. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10